# Problem with new files on Ubuntu Server on VBox

Tags: php, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine (VirtualBox) running latest ubuntu server as my personal/development web server.

My configuration is the following:
My web server (running Zend Server CE) is running on the virtual machine.
My files, are on my host machine (Win7) and all the virtula machine does is to serve the files from a shared folder.

So if I go to /home/ronaldo/htdocs/project_name I can see all my files for that project - the shared folder in this case is the main folder - htdocs.

I use VirtualHost - so every new project has an address such as project_name.local.

Every now and then, when I add new files to a project - say, using Dreamweaver, PHPDesigner or even Internet explorer, that file is not recognized on the server.

It was working fine.
I think my last major change was to upgrade the server to the latest some weeks ago I think.

Now, lets say I'm working on an Opencart ecommerce project and I am creating a new module, with controllers, views, etc. The new files are not recognized until I reboot my server.

When I try to list the files on my web-server using "ls" - the new files appear in red.

Why is that?

Anyone has a similar setup or can help me with a workaround not to have to reboot the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmount/Mount the shared folder : http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_manual
You may get more specific help at virtualbox forums.

Or if it is an option, you can create a windows share and use that from Linux.

Comment: Will try that as soon as I get home and face the problem again. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using VBox share then you should contact them on their forums, this definitely sounds like a bug to me. Or you can create a windows share/ ftp share and mount it on your linux system.

Comment: I did some updates. Now your mount/umount idea is working. Thanks.